# Indented button effect CSS

Tags: button, css

I'm trying to create an indented button look similar to DuckDuckGo's 'more' button.

[image]

The image on the left is DuckDuck's, the right mine. The very bottom shadow is what I'm trying to re-create. Zoomed in they look like:
[image]

For now, I've used their background header image and button background (not apart of fiddle). This fiddle is the code so far. Using IE9 Dev tools, I turned off all the other styles etc in DuckDuck's that were not relevant. As far as I can tell, for the life of me, I cannot see how they achieve the shadow effect...

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25Hhu/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7Y4hK/1/